# Populate text boxes when Combo Box selection made

Tags: vb.net, combobox

Im working on an application in Visual Studio 2013, using Visual Basic, there's something im slightly held up on hoping you might be able to help me out.. okay so I have my user for with a Combo Box which is bound to a table in access it pulls the data nicely, for 'Customer Name' but what I  would like to do is write a code so when the 'Customer Name' is selected in the Combo Box selection below some text boxes automatically fill with the 'Customer Address' 'Customer Phone Number' 'Customer Account Name' I have a working code for this but unfortunately it only works with Int32 I would like it to identify using text. can anyone help? I will follow up with my previous code as an aid

Thanks James

```
    Private Sub cmdGetByIdentifier_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdGetByIdentifier.Click
If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtIdentifier1.Text) Then
    Dim Identifier As Int32 = 0
    If Int32.TryParse(txtIdentifier1.Text, Identifier) Then
        txtCompanyName1.Text = GetCustomerNameByIdentifier(Identifier)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("'" & txtIdentifier1.Text & "' is not a valid integer.")
    End If
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Must enter an identifier to get a company name.")
End If
 End Sub

 Private Sub cmdGetCustomer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdGetCustomer.Click
If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtIdentifier2.Text) Then
    Dim Identifier As Int32 = 0
    If Int32.TryParse(txtIdentifier2.Text, Identifier) Then
        Dim Cust As Customer = GetCustomer(Identifier)
        txtCompanyName2.Text = Cust.Name
        txtContactName2.Text = Cust.ContactName
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("'" & txtIdentifier1.Text & "' is not a valid integer.")
    End If
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Must enter an identifier to get a company name.")
End If

 End Sub
 End Class
```

```
    Module DatabaseOperations
    Public Function GetCustomerNameByIdentifier(ByVal Identifier As Int32) As String
Dim CompanyName As String = ""
Dim Builder As New OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With {.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0", .DataSource = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Database1.accdb")}
Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = Builder.ConnectionString}
    Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand With {.Connection = cn}
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CompanyName FROM Customer WHERE Identifier =@P1"
        Dim NameParameter As New OleDb.OleDbParameter With {.DbType = DbType.Int32, .ParameterName = "P1", .Value = Identifier}
        cmd.Parameters.Add(NameParameter)
        cn.Open()
        CompanyName = CStr(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
    End Using
End Using
Return CompanyName
End Function
Public Function GetCustomer(ByVal Identifier As Int32) As Customer
Dim Customer As New Customer

 Dim CompanyName As String = ""
Dim Builder As New OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With {.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0", .DataSource = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Database1.accdb")}
Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = Builder.ConnectionString}
    Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand With {.Connection = cn}
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Identifier, CompanyName,ContactName FROM Customer WHERE Identifier =@P1"
        Dim NameParameter As New OleDb.OleDbParameter With {.DbType = DbType.Int32, .ParameterName = "P1", .Value = Identifier}
        cmd.Parameters.Add(NameParameter)
        cn.Open()
        Dim Reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If Reader.HasRows Then
            Reader.Read()
            Customer.Identifier = Identifier
            Customer.Name = Reader.GetString(1)
            Customer.ContactName = Reader.GetString(2)
        End If
    End Using
End Using

Return Customer

End Function
End Module
```

```
Public Class Customer
Public Property Identifier As Int32
Public Property Name As String
Public Property ContactName As String
Public Sub New()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Anyone any ideas for this question?

Comment: Create another `GetCustomerNameByIdentifier` that takes a string instead and pass the string. Then change your SQL to whatever field you want to query.

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you mean @Steve , would you mind explaining a little more

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
Public Function GetCustomerNameByName(ByVal Name As String) As String
Dim CompanyName As String = ""
Dim Builder As New OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With {.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0", .DataSource = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Database1.accdb")}
Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = Builder.ConnectionString}
    Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand With {.Connection = cn}
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CompanyName FROM Customer WHERE CustName =@P1"
        Dim NameParameter As New OleDb.OleDbParameter With {.DbType = DbType.String, .ParameterName = "P1", .Value = Name}
        cmd.Parameters.Add(NameParameter)
        cn.Open()
        CompanyName = CStr(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
    End Using
End Using
Return CompanyName
End Function
```

Comment: It still has the validation code though cmd.CommandText="SELECT CompanyName FROM Customer WHERE CustName=@P1" in the data operationcs code @p1 is if Int32? Im not sure if im mistaking myself

Comment: Sorry, I missed changing the parameter type to string.

Comment: Hi @Steve , I just ran that code and it seems to load then get an OleDbException was unhandled , and give the following : An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: No value given for one or more required parameters.  - suggesting it cant see the table or DB

Comment: Try changing this line `Dim NameParameter As New OleDb.OleDbParameter With {.DbType = DbType.String, .ParameterName = "P1", .Value = Name}` to this line `Dim NameParameter As New OleDb.OleDbParameter With {.DbType = DbType.String, .ParameterName = "@P1", .Value = Name}`. Notice the @P1 parameter name.

Comment: I just saw something else, you set the value in that line to NAME, which would be the NAME of your form/class you are in. If you change that to `NameParameter`, you can remove the line below it. This would not really cause you a problem but it was just a waste if time.

Comment: Hi Steve, Still get a problem here ,An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: No value given for one or more required parameters.  , even with the parameters changed.

Comment: Hi Steve, would you mind taking a look at my MSDN article, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9598f856-2ee4-4919-a017-5eec01a42e0d/populate-textbox-after-combo-box-selection-display-data-in-text-boxes-after-combo-box-selection-vb?forum=winforms , It explains exactly what im trying to do

Comment: Double check that the fields "CompanyName" and "CustName" exist in your "Customer" table and they are spelled correctly.

Comment: Hi Steve, Yes that was one of my first port of calls, all spelling is correct, and the fields and table exist. Thanks James